# How to use audio tag in jsp with a web source? - grails

Tags: jsp, grails

```
<audio autoplay="" src="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=hello%20world"></audio>
```

This works fine in html, but not in a gsp.
Feedback:
GET http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=hello%20world 404 (Not Found)
Curious: if i use the url (direct) one time, the received mp3 (from google) is in cache and it works.
This works too (in jsp):

```
<iframe src="http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=hello%20world"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google blocks calls with referer (and from unwelcomed user agents).  By clicking the link in your browser, you are sending a referer.

Works not (No referer, cURL useragent):

```
curl -v 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=hello%20world'
```

Works (No referer):

```
curl -v -A 'Mozialla' 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=hello%20world'
```

Works not:

```
curl -v -A 'Mozialla' -e 'www.stackoverflow.com' 'http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=utf-8&tl=en&q=hello%20world'
```

Comment: Thanks! You're so right. This works: [http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?lang=ge&q=hello%20world.](http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?lang=ge&q=hello%20world.) 
Does anybody know a similiar german service? I need a URL not a website!